# Browser key option not showing in google console

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-apps

I have installed a map plugin in my wordpress website and it is asking for broswer key and server key. so i created an app in google console and when i try to create api key there were no options for creating browser key and server key. there is a default api key option. you could see it in screenshot.[image]

I had worked on google api's previously and there were options for browser key and server. however i cannot find them this time. 
Are these options get removed from google api or am i missing something.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the interface has changed.  Click on "Restrict Key", then on "HTTP referrers (web sites)" to get to the list of allowed websites for an browser key.

For a server key, do the same, just choose "IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)"

[Related issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10464)